# Data out of cfit of sfit Matlab object

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to extract data out of cfit or sfit object? I want to extract matrix of fitted values out of sfit object without accessing to every element of fit (very slow in 240x320 ). Problem is equivalent to extraction of vector out of cfit object. Is there a method defined over this object, or something similar?

Please, post a code! 
thanks, Nikola

Answer (score 1):

You can access an element of an sfit object with sfit.element.  For example:

```
sf = fit([x,y],z,'poly23');
sf

     Linear model Poly23:
     sf(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p21*x^2*y
                    + p12*x*y^2 + p03*y^3
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p00 =       1.118  (0.9149, 1.321)
       p10 =  -0.0002941  (-0.000502, -8.623e-05)
       p01 =       1.533  (0.7032, 2.364)
       p20 =  -1.966e-08  (-7.084e-08, 3.152e-08)
       p11 =   0.0003427  (-0.0001009, 0.0007863)
       p02 =      -6.951  (-8.421, -5.481)
       p21 =   9.563e-08  (6.276e-09, 1.85e-07)
       p12 =  -0.0004401  (-0.0007082, -0.0001721)
       p03 =       4.999  (4.082, 5.917)
```

To get one element of sf:

```
sf.p03

ans =

    4.9994
```